# Precalculate Perl constants based on some run-time calculated value

Tags: perl, constants

This should be rather trivial, but I cannot figure it out on my own.
Having the code below, are there any ways to get rid of many invocations of `dirname(rel2abs($0))`?

```
package Foo;

use File::Basename;
use File::Spec::Functions qw/rel2abs/;
use Carp qw/croak/;
use 5.010;

use constant BAR_NAMES => {
    WATER => dirname(rel2abs($0)) . '/../data/water.png',
    FIRE => dirname(rel2abs($0)) .'/../data/fire.png',
    GRASS => dirname(rel2abs($0)) .'/../data/grass.png'#,
    #and so on
};

sub get {
    my ($self, $name) = (shift, shift);
    if (exists BAR_NAMES->{$name}) {
        #return some calculated data based on $name value
    } else {
        croak("Constant `$name` is not declared.");
    }
};

1;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $dirname;
BEGIN { $dirname = dirname(rel2abs($0)); }

use constant BAR_NAMES => {
    WATER => $dirname . '/../data/water.png',
    FIRE => $dirname .'/../data/fire.png',
    GRASS => $dirname .'/../data/grass.png'#,
    #and so on
};
```

You need a `BEGIN` block because any expression in a `use` statement is evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 6):

You could roll it in a `map`:

```
use constant BAR_NAMES =>
{
   map { uc( $_ ) => dirname(rel2abs($0)) . "/../data/$_.png" }
     qw< water fire grass >
};
```

If I am not mistaken, the `dirname` should not be necessary:

```
use constant BAR_NAMES =>
{
   map { uc( $_ ) => rel2abs("$0/../data/$_.png") }
     qw< water fire grass >
};
```

Comment: `uc( $_ )` could also be written as `+uc`

Comment: Thanks, but in that case it will be calculated many times. But I want to avoid that.

Comment: @varnie: if you ran it a hundred times a day for the rest of your life, it may add up to enough time to be noticeable.

Comment: @ysth: maybe it matters if the underlying file system is Andrew File System or curlftpfs or so...

Answer (score 5):

On top of the great existing answers, there's also

```
use constant PROJ_ROOT => dirname(rel2abs($0)) . '/..';

use constant BAR_NAMES => {
    WATER => PROJ_ROOT.'/data/water.png',
    FIRE  => PROJ_ROOT.'/data/fire.png',
    GRASS => PROJ_ROOT.'/data/grass.png',
};
```

and

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

use constant BAR_NAMES => {
    WATER => "$RealBin/../data/water.png",
    FIRE  => "$RealBin/../data/fire.png",
    GRASS => "$RealBin/../data/grass.png",
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use constant BAR_NAMES => do {
    my $dirname = dirname(rel2abs($0));
    {
        WATER => $dirname . '/../data/water.png',
        FIRE => $dirname .'/../data/fire.png',
        GRASS => $dirname .'/../data/grass.png'#,
        #and so on
    }
};
```